# Chart going out of the specified area in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, telerik

I am drawing a chart using radcartesian chart.chart is inside a stack panel ,
stack panel is inside a grid.and all this is in a data template .
problem is my chart goes out of the area of  panel.and two charts get overlapped.
I have tried setting Maxheight property to telerik:RadCartesianChart but still its not working
my datatemplate inside the xaml is as follows.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataGridRow">

                <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="45"></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="590"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="110"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


                <telerik:Label Name="Criteria" Margin="5" Background="White" Height="23" Width="100" Grid.Column="0"  Content="{Binding CriteriaName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBox Background="White" Name="txtLow" TextAlignment="Center" Height="23" Width="60" Margin="1.5" Grid.Column="1" KeyDown="SliderValues_KeyDown" Text="{Binding SelectionLow, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource formatLowerValue}}">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DataContext.LowValueChangedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" >
                            <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="radGridView" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="txtLow" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                        </KeyBinding>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{Binding DataContext.LowValueChangedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" >
                            <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="radGridView" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="txtLow" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                        </KeyBinding>
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>

                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                            <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.LowValueChangedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" >
                                <Commands:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="radGridView" />
                                        <Binding ElementName="txtLow" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Commands:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                            </Commands:EventToCommand>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                        <!--<i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
                            <i:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding DataContext.SliderValueKeyDownCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtLow}"/>
                        </i:EventTrigger>-->
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Margin="7,-72,7.5,0">
                        <!--<Grid Grid.Column="2" >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>-->

                        <telerik:RadCartesianChart Palette="Summer">
                            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                                <telerik:CategoricalAxis Visibility="Hidden"/>
                            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.HorizontalAxis>
                            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                            <telerik:LinearAxis Visibility="Hidden" MajorStep="30"/><!--</telerik:LinearAxis>MajorStep="{Binding DataContext.MajorStepValue,Mode=TwoWay,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"/>-->
                            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.VerticalAxis>
                            <telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
                                <telerik:BarSeries ItemsSource="{Binding KeyValue, Mode=TwoWay}" CategoryBinding="Key" ValueBinding="Value">
                                    <telerik:BarSeries.PointTemplates>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Rectangle Width="3" Fill="#FF3276b1"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </telerik:BarSeries.PointTemplates>
                                </telerik:BarSeries>
                            </telerik:RadCartesianChart.Series>
                        </telerik:RadCartesianChart>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <telerik:RadSlider Name="CriteriaSlider" Grid.Column="2" ToolTip="Movable" Minimum="{Binding LowValue,Mode=TwoWay}"  Height="13" Margin="5"  Maximum="{Binding HighValue,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionEnd="{Binding SelectionHigh,Mode=TwoWay}"  SelectionStart="{Binding SelectionLow,Mode=TwoWay}"  TickPlacement="TopLeft"   IsSelectionRangeEnabled="True" IsDirectionReversed="False" SmallChange="10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" >
                    <!--TickFrequency="{Binding TickFreq,Mode=TwoWay}"-->
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                            <Commands:EventToCommand  Command="{Binding DataContext.SliderSelectionChangedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}"  >
                                <Commands:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="radGridView" />
                                        <Binding ElementName="CriteriaSlider" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Commands:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                            </Commands:EventToCommand>

                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <telerik:RadSlider.TickTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="7" Foreground="Transparent"/>
                                <Label Content="{Binding DrawHistoragm}"/>-->
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadSlider.TickTemplate>
                </telerik:RadSlider>
                    <!--</Grid>-->
                    <!--<telerik:Label Background="White" Height="23" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="70" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding SelectionHigh, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource formatCell}}"/>-->
                <TextBox Background="White" TextAlignment="Center" Name="txtHigh" Height="23" Width="60" Margin="3" Grid.Column="3" KeyDown="SliderValues_KeyDown" Text="{Binding SelectionHigh, Mode=TwoWay,Converter={StaticResource formatCell}}">
                    <TextBox.InputBindings>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding DataContext.HighValueChangedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" >
                            <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="radGridView" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="txtHigh" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                        </KeyBinding>
                        <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{Binding DataContext.HighValueChangedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" >
                            <KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="radGridView" />
                                    <Binding ElementName="txtHigh" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </KeyBinding.CommandParameter>
                        </KeyBinding>
                    </TextBox.InputBindings>
                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                            <Commands:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DataContext.HighValueChangedCmd,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}" >
                                <Commands:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                                        <Binding ElementName="radGridView" />
                                        <Binding ElementName="txtHigh" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </Commands:EventToCommand.CommandParameter>
                            </Commands:EventToCommand>
                        </i:EventTrigger>
                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBox>
                <telerik:RadButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="4" Height="Auto" Width="70"  MinHeight="20" MinWidth="25" MaxHeight="30" MaxWidth="30" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Summer" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource WhiteImageButton}" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteItem,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type telerik:RadWindow}}}"  >
                    <telerik:RadButton.CommandParameter>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverter}">
                            <Binding ElementName="radGridView" />
                            <Binding ElementName="Criteria" />
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </telerik:RadButton.CommandParameter>
                </telerik:RadButton>

            </Grid>
```

Comment: have you tried setting margin/padding to the chart? that might prevent the overlap.

Comment: I have checked we can not set the padding of a row.Can you show some code?

Comment: I also noticed you have several elements in the same column as the chart. You could put every element in its own column or give the stackpanel a width (or min-width). also what happens if you set the margin of the stackpanel to 50 instead of Margin="7,-72,7.5,0" ?